# Finding the dictionary to see the users last queried tables

Tags: oracle, database-administration

i need the dictionary from where i can see the users last query time on each table.
I know the sys.all_objects, it shows the last ddl time, I need to see when the user queried the table. Hope you will help me to find the solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not store last queried date either by table or by user. You would need to **enable select auditing** to capture this, but that can use a **lot of space**, introduces a performance impact on users, and become quickly unmanageable on a busy database.

However, if you are okay with less than perfect 100% accuracy, you can approximate what you need by using **Active Session History (ASH)** data, at least as far back as your retention allows. The downside to this is that the on-disk version of this data stores only 1 out of every 10 samples (samples are taken once per second), so if a query ran for less than 10 seconds it might not be captured. That will drop a lot of small stuff that you may need, so this may not be acceptable for that reason:

```
SELECT /*+ USE_HASH(plan t ash u) PARALLEL(4) NO_MERGE(t) NO_MERGE(ash) NO_MERGE(u) */
       u.username,
       t.owner table_owner,
       t.table_name,
       MAX(ash.sample_time) last_access_time
  FROM (SELECT /*+ NO_MERGE */ sql_id,plan_hash_value,object_name,object_owner
          FROM dba_hist_sql_plan
         WHERE object_name IS NOT NULL
           AND object_type = 'TABLE'
         GROUP BY sql_id,plan_hash_value,object_name,object_owner) plan,
       dba_tables t,
       dba_hist_active_sess_history ash,
       dba_users u
 WHERE plan.object_owner = t.owner
   AND plan.object_name = t.table_name
   AND plan.sql_id = ash.sql_id
   AND plan.plan_hash_value = ash.sql_plan_hash_value
   AND ash.user_id = u.user_id
 GROUP BY u.username,
          t.owner,
          t.table_name
```

One option to get around the 1-out-of-10 issue is to have a job that runs every half hour or so and captures this info from the in-memory version of ASH, which is at a 1-second granularity, so much less likely to miss stuff (it will still miss some sub-second activity):

```
SELECT /*+ USE_HASH(plan t ash u) PARALLEL(4) NO_MERGE(t) NO_MERGE(ash) NO_MERGE(u) */
       u.username,
       t.owner table_owner,
       t.table_name,
       MAX(ash.sample_time) last_access_time
  FROM (SELECT /*+ NO_MERGE */ sql_id,plan_hash_value,object_name,object_owner
          FROM gv$sql_plan
         WHERE object_name IS NOT NULL
           AND object_type = 'TABLE'
         GROUP BY sql_id,plan_hash_value,object_name,object_owner) plan,
       dba_tables t,
       gv$active_session_history ash,
       dba_users u
 WHERE plan.object_owner = t.owner
   AND plan.object_name = t.table_name
   AND plan.sql_id = ash.sql_id
   AND plan.plan_hash_value = ash.sql_plan_hash_value
   AND ash.user_id = u.user_id
 GROUP BY u.username,
          t.owner,
          t.table_name
```

Then record that to a table and keep merging/updating it with the latest `last_access_time` result for each key every time you run it. I suggest roughly once per half hour because in-memory ASH data needs to still be present (it rolls off after awhile) and you need your cursors to still be present in the shared pool. You may need to adjust this suggested interval given your particular database's behavior. (I do this every 10 minutes in my footprint just to be on the safe side due to the unpredictability of cursor lifespan in the shared pool since I have a few databases that age out their cursors after as little as 30 minutes).

So again, if you need perfect accuracy you'll need to use Oracle's auditing functionality, but you'll probably find it that it uses too much space. This is a lightweight option that is less than perfectly accurate but given your situation may meet your needs.